# update contact details on Android

Tags: android, contacts

I would like my code to update **contact details** (like name, phone number, email, organization details, etc) in the android contact book. I was successful in modifying a few (name, phone number and email to be specific) but not all.

Whenever I try to update the organization details (Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY and Contacts.Organizations.TITLE) for a contact my app throws an **exception**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot update URL: content://contacts/people/69/organizations/69
```

the code snippet is as follows:

```
Uri baseUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, 69);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                new String[] { Contacts.Organizations._ID, Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY,Contacts.Organizations.TITLE}, 
                null, null, null);
if(c.getCount() > 0) {
      uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, c.getString(0));
ContentValues val1 = new ContentValues();
val1.put(Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY, "arw");
val1.put(Contacts.Organizations.TYPE, Contacts.Organizations.TYPE_WORK);
val1.put(Contacts.Organizations.TITLE, "abcdef");
this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, val1);
```

Comment: This isn't a question.  Before anyone can help, you need to explain what you think is the problem, and give us more information.

Comment: Whenever I try to update the organization details (Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY and Contacts.Organizations.TITLE) for a contact my app throws an exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot update URL: content://contacts/people/69/organizations/69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update any data in the contacts you need to know the existing id for that fields. Then I used the Builder class to obtain separate ContentProviderOperation objects for the various fields I wanted to update, add them to an arrayList and then use the ContentProvider.applyBatch() method

Comment: And how did you find the id for a particular contact?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to update the company and title information. The following now works for me.

```
Uri workUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            values.clear();
            values.put(android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY, "company");
            values.put(android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.TYPE, android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.TYPE_WORK);
            values.put(android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.TITLE, "job title");
            values.put(android.provider.Contacts.Organizations.ISPRIMARY, 1);
            getContentResolver().insert(workUri, values);
```

Comment: this will insert a new company. What I'm looking for is something which updates an exustung compnay details

Comment: Any way I found the answer myself. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID };
        String where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
        String[] selection = new String[] { String.valueOf(1) };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, selection, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            Log.e("id",""+c.getString(0));
            c.moveToNext();
        }



        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.clear();
        values.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID , 0);
        getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values,ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "+ ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(1) });
```