# Can not update contact using ContentProvoider

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

```
Uri name=null;
           String []whereargs={"Sameer Ahmad"};
    name=Uri.withAppendedPath(People.CONTENT_URI,People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    cv1.put(People.NAME,"Tofeeq Ahmad");
    int i1=0;
    i1=getContentResolver().update(name,cv1,"name=?",whereargs);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
```

I am trying to update a phone numder by URi but its showing the `Exception:Cannot Update//Contacts/people/phone.`Same error in inserting.

1. I want to create shared data base which will be accessible from every application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you declared the necessary permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Yes..Mark i have declared permission

Comment: Exact Exception is this....            java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot update URL: content://contacts/people/phones

Comment: Please post the full exception including the stack trace in to your initial question.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200436/update-contact-details-on-android

Comment: No this is diffrent..can you tell me why this exception is coming.I have posted complete code for insert